# Search list of object based on specific attribute c#

Tags: c#, list, search, object

i have this class:

```
   class Article
    {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    List<Article> arts = new List<Article>();
```

I have a list of objects. These objects have two variables ID, Name. I need to check if in this list there is an article with name = "Cheese". How can I do to make this search returns a Boolean value?  Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool hasCheese = arts.Any(a => a.Name == "Cheese");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: -

```
bool contains = arts.Any(x => x.Name == "Cheese");
```

`Any` will return a bool indicating whether or not the list contains `Cheese`